# Insert path in REQUEST_URI while checking if file exists using RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to write a .htaccess code which should work in root directory as well as children directories.

This is how sample requests will look like: `/z` `/a/z` `/a/b/z`

For each case, I want to check if these respective file (`/m/z`, `/a/m/z`, `/a/b/m/z`) exists using `RewriteCond` . if they exist, follow this `RewriteRule` rule `RewriteRule .* code.php?alias=$0 [QSA]`.

I am unable to write this special `RewriteCond` for this case and need help with it. Note I cannot used `RewriteBase`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally am able to find a solution which seems to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*)?/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/m/%2 -f
RewriteRule .* %1/code.php?alias=%2
```